# What is the meaning of 'furled' in "The smoke furled dreamily from its navy blue nostrils"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> The smoke *furled* 
>   dreamily from its navy blue nostrils and wafted gently into the evening, almost 
>   indistinguishable from the exhaust fumes of the cars below it.

I'm unsure what the meaning of *furl* is in the sentence above, which is quoted from *Three Times Table* by Sara Maitland.

Merriam Webster's definition of *furl*:

> - transitive verb : to wrap or roll (as a sail or a flag) close to or around something
> - intransitive verb : to curl or fold as in being furled

Can anybody explain which of the Merriam Webster definitions better fits Sara Maitland's usage?

Comment: What if Sara Maitland just made up the word, and didn't look in the dictionary?

Comment: Check out the poem *Jabberwocky* by Lewis Carrol. The poem is a specimen of English literature and has a meaning, yet it contains many words that do not appear anywhere in the dictionary (and whose origin, if they are used anywhere else, can be traced to *Jabberwocky*).

Comment: For instance, the word *chortled* appears in Jabberwocky. That's a word now. But it first appeared in that poem. Today you can chortle. Similarly Sara Maitland's meaning does not depend on whether or not an intransitive usage of *furled* is in a dictionary, or whether it exists at all.

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely an intransitive usage—there is no object.

The picture I imagine is that smoke is rising, curling like a ribbon waving gently in a breeze.

Comment: To elaborate on the imagery a bit, the smoke probably starts by coming out in a fairly straight, thin stream, but quickly starts to become wavy and then curly as it loses speed; after a very short distance it is moving quite slowly ('wafting') in a mass which still exhibits some remnants of the original stream-like appearance; you could call it a cloud at this point, but you can still pick out "ribbons" folded around and wadded up within the cloud.

Comment: @Hellion & Barbara, don't you note something strange in 'furled *from*'? Assuming that furl=fold, how can the smoke 'fold *from*' its nostrils? Maybe then could it be 'fold *upon*', not *from*.

Comment: The usage of 'furled' in general is pretty rare, so it's probably intended as a poetic, evocative expression rather than as a strictly literal description.  (Ordinarily, as the definition implies, I'd only expect 'furl' to be applied to a flag, banner, or other large displayed fabric.)

Comment: @Carlo_R Think of it as *curling* rather than *folding*; and then take a look at [these images](http://jeffcable.blogspot.com/2010/07/photographing-smoke-too-much-fun.html) of smoke furling away from a stick of incense.